# Show that $E\left[(\hat{\mu}[n+1]-m)^2 \right] \le E\left[(\hat{\mu}[c]-m)^2 \right] $ (minimizing expected MSE)

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, mean-square-error, parameter-estimation

Give a sample $(X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n)$ where $X_i$'s are i.i.d exponential random variables. with parameter $\frac{1}{m}$ (mean $m$). Let

$$\mathcal T=\{\hat{\mu}[c] \, \vert\, c>0\} \hspace{0.5cm} \text{and} \hspace{0.5cm} \hat{\mu}\,[c]=\frac{1}{c}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$.

Show that the estimator $\hat{\mu}[n+1]$ has the smallest expected MSE. In other words, I want to show that:

$$E\left[(\hat{\mu}[n+1]-m)^2 \right] \le E\left[(\hat{\mu}[c]-m)^2 \right] $$

**What I have tried so far:**

$$\begin{aligned}E\left[(\hat{\mu}[n+1]-m)^2 \right] &=\big(E\left[\hat{\mu}[n+1]-m \right]\big)^2+\text{Var}(\hat{\mu}[n+1]) \\[5pt] &=\big(E\left[\hat{\mu}[n+1]\right]-E[m] \big)^2+\text{Var}(\hat{\mu}[n+1]) \\[5pt] &= \left(E\left[\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right]-m \right)^2+  \text{Var}(\hat{\mu}[n+1]) \\[5pt] &= \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i]-m \right)^2+  \text{Var}(\hat{\mu}[n+1]) \\[5pt] &= \left( \frac{nm}{n+1}-m\right)^2+\text{Var}(\hat{\mu}[n+1] \\[5pt] &= \frac{m^2}{(n+1)^2} +\text{Var}(\hat{\mu}[n+1] \le\ldots?\end{aligned}$$

I was trying to get to an expression that I could show is minimized for $c=n+1$ but I am not able to rewrite the variance and I am not sure if this is the right approach. Alternatively I was thinking of trying to show that $c=n+1$ minimizes the expected MSW by doing some sort of differentiation but that didn't work either. How can I show this statement is true?

---

**Edit:** Based on the answer from heropup, I calculated the minimum and bias.

Minimizing the expression:

$$\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        &\phantom{\iff} \, \, \,\frac{d}{dc}\left(\frac{m^2(c-n)^2+m^2n}{c^2}\right) = 0
        \\[10pt] &\iff \frac{2m^2(c-n)-2c(m^2(c-n)^2+m^2n}{c^4}=0
        \\[10pt] &\iff 2(c-n)c^2-2c(m^2(c-n)^2+m^2n)=0
        \\[10pt] &\iff 2nc^2-2n^2c-2nc=0
        \\[10pt] &\iff c(c-n-1)=0
        \\[10pt] &\iff c=n+1
    \end{split}
\end{equation*} $$

We also have $$\frac{d^2}{dc^2}\left(\frac{m^2(c-n)^2+m^2n}{c^2}\right)=\frac{2m^2 n(3n-2x+3)}{x^4}$$

and at the point $n+1$ the second derivative is positive since $n,m>0$ adn therefore:

$$\frac{2m^2 n(n+1)}{(n+1)^4}>0$$

Therefore the expected MSE is minimized for $c=n+1$ and the inequality holds.

For the bias:

$$\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        E\left[\hat{\mu}[n+1]\right]-m &= E\left[ \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^n\right]-m
        \\[10pt] &= \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i]-m
        \\[10pt] &= \frac{1}{n+1} nm-m
        \\[10pt] &= m\left(\frac{n}{n+1}-1 \right) \not= m
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}$$

Therefore this estimator is biased with the bias calculated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = c \hat \mu[c]$$ be the sample total, which is not dependent on the choice of $c$.  What is the mean and variance of this random variable?  Since the $X_i$ are iid exponential, it is easy to see $$\operatorname{E}[Y_n] = n \operatorname{E}[X_1] = nm, \quad \operatorname{Var}[Y_n] = n \operatorname{Var}[X_1] = nm^2.$$  Then the bias of the estimator $\hat \mu[c]$ is simply $$\operatorname{Bias}[\hat \mu[c]] = \operatorname{E}[\hat \mu[c] - m] = \frac{nm}{c} - m = \left(\frac{n}{c} - 1 \right) m$$ and the variance of the estimator is $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat \mu[c]] = \operatorname{Var}[Y_n/c] = \frac{n}{c^2} m^2.$$  So the MSE is $$\operatorname{MSE}[\hat \mu[c]] = \operatorname{Bias}^2[\hat \mu[c]] + \operatorname{Var}[\hat \mu[c]] = \left(\left(\frac{n}{c} - 1\right)^2 + \frac{n}{c^2} \right) m^2 = \frac{(c-n)^2 + n}{c^2} m^2.$$

For what value of $c$ is this function minimized?  We can clearly ignore $m^2$, so treat this as a continuous function of $c$ for fixed $m, n$, differentiate with respect to $c$, locate its critical point(s), and the rest is obvious.

---

The key strategic concept that you overlooked here is that you sought to compute the MSE for the specific choice that already minimizes it, namely $c = n+1$, rather than to compute it for a *general* value of $c$ and using calculus to find the global minimum.  This latter approach, as you can see, is much easier.

As a further exercise, note that this choice for $c$ does *not* result in an unbiased estimator.  What is the bias?  How does this example illustrate the concept of "variance-bias tradeoff" with respect to parameter estimation?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I added some calculations in my post for the minimization of $c$ and the calculation for the bias. I am just not sure about the concept of "variance-bias tradeoff". As far as I understand, minimizing the variance would give me the largest bias and vice versa in theory right? I tried to play around with the equations to find a minimum for the variance but the variance doesn't have a minimum in this case right?

Comment: @Nullspace Your calculations are correct.  As for the "tradeoff," this problem illustrates how it is not always desirable to choose an unbiased estimator, because doing so may result in a larger variance, which in turn leads to a larger MSE.  In this case, the variance is proportional to $1/c^2$, so as $c \to \infty$, the variance goes to $0$ and the bias goes to infinity.  But by choosing a slightly larger $c$, we get a smaller variance at the expense of some bias, and your calculation shows the choice $c = n+1$ is in a sense "optimal" in terms of this tradeoff.

Comment: That makes so much sense! I see now that all you have just written is basically described by the MSE formula but just reading it made it click for me! Thank you so much!